# Can a Completed task be edited?

Tags: tasks

Excuse me if this is an "obvious" question, but I cannot find a clear answer anywhere.  If a user has edit access to a Task, can that Task still be edited when the status changed to 'Completed' and it's moved to the Activity History?  Common sense would dictate that moving the status to Completed locks the record, but that does not appear to be the case based on my testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, users can still edit tasks after they are marked as Completed. You could use a validation rule to stop this pretty easily.